# Sqlite to csv to excel conversion not inserting values in columns

Tags: python, excel, sqlite, csv

I am bringing in data from one database into another. Once there i use this sqlite table to create a csv file. From this csv file I want to create an excel file with the same information. The data however is not being inserted into the appropriate columns on excel but rather inserting entire rowsas a csv file. There are 7 columns, the first two are blank while the others have values.

I have tried using other libraries but this configuration is the only one that gives me a non-blank result.

```
 import sqlite3 
 import pyodbc
 from datetime import date, datetime
 import csv
 import os
 import glob
 from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook   

 def write_CSV(rows):
    filename = "weekly.csv"

    # Begin file writing
    with open(filename, "w", newline="") as csvFile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
        #write row
        writer.writerow
        # Column headings
        writer.writerow(
            [   "Impacts --- products ",
               "FOSS name",
               "CVE_id",
               "CVSS_Score",
               "N--T_NVD_CVE_Description",
               "Date_Orginally_Published",
               "Reference",
           ]
       )
        for row in rows:
           #test to see if data is there
           #print(row) 
        writer.writerow(('','',row))

def gen_excel():
    for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
        workbook = Workbook(csvfile[:-4] + '.xlsx')
        worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
        with open(csvfile, 'rt', encoding='utf8') as f:
           reader = csv.reader(f)
           for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                for c, col in enumerate(row):
                    worksheet.write(r, c, col)
     workbook.close()
```

The excel file is basically the same csv file with the xlsx extension with the columns on the first row and then just all the data inserted in one row separated by commas.

Comment: Do you have considerd to use pandas? There you can do: `read_sql_table(...`, `.to_csv(...` and `.to_excel(...`

Comment: I have, i actually got this code to work, the issue is im trying to leave the first two columns blank as it shows here writer.writerow(('','',row)). Is there a better way to do this? My rows are wrapped in ( ) so every row is inserted in the first column. When i remove this it works fine.

Comment: ***"trying to leave the first two columns blank"***: [Edit] your question and show the output of one line `print(row)`.

Comment: I actually figured it out! But thank you for the advice and input. Sometimes you just gotta drink coffee and error your way to a solution haha